# Approach towards a arranging and displaying a set of Group in Adobe Air/Flex

Tags: apache-flex, user-interface, air

I have been doing UI for web application until now and am pretty new to flex. I have been working on an application lately which requires a set of 4-5 different views. 
Lets say for example:-

View 1: List of all Students and their details
View 2: List of all Faculty and their details
View 3: List of all non-faculty staff
View 4: Some data analysis based on performance of students etc
View 5: some misc stuff

Now I tried hooking these views (by view I mean the parent container component. I am using *Group*) in **TabNavigator** but the end result looked pretty lame to me - it looked like a website with 5 tabs showing different information.

I like the way how Salesforce implements the application view for their dashboards, so now I have a drop down list which has references hooked up to the parent Group of these views. On selection, I make the respective Group visible and hide the others. So far it works absolutely fine on the UI front.
Behind the UI, what's happening is that all the 5 **Groups** are present, but only one of them is visible at any point in time. With every selection, I have to set other groups to invisible.

However, I don't feel that this is a good approach. Can there be a better solution than making the Groups visible and invisible! Does TabNavigator work the same way?

I am open to other ideas as well. Any help/view/recommendations on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **TabNavigator** is a [ViewStack](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/containers/ViewStack.html).
A **ViewStack** contains a collection of containers, and only one of them is visible at a given point. You can manipulate the *selectedChild* or *selectedIndex* properties of the **ViewStack** to control which is visible. You can extend the **ViewStack** and customize it, or just use one to control your collection of **Groups**. I'm pretty sure that the hidden containers are not included in the Flex life-cycle, which makes it a good choice to use.

Comment: Naor, thanks for the input. Do you think my approach towards the the design is correct? I am trying to stay away from tabbed look. Do think implementing my own ViewStack would give me some advantage? If the same procedure of hiding and showing components is being followed in ViewStack, then can I continue with my approach as mentioned in the question above?

Comment: I think that the main benefit of using a ViewStack is that it's easy to associate it with any option-based control you need. The ViewStack does'nt enforce the tabbed look. The TabNavigator is basically a ViewStack composed with a TabBar. It looks to me that using the ViewStack instead of a homebrewed solution is also better since it probably already handles all the possible pitfalls and uses the best practices for this use-case.

Comment: Hi Naor, do you know a possible approach to this question:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416509/adobe-air-null-pointers-when-rendering-takes-time